# How to open Visio template (i.e. .vstx) for editing from a VSTO Add-in

Tags: c#, interop, vsto, office-interop, visio

I am writing a VSTO Add-in for Excel that uses Visio, and a Visio template (i.e. .vstx) to create a customized Gantt chart using the contents of a table (i.e. ListObject).

I would like to open the Visio template for editing from the Excel Add-in by pressing a button on the ribbon. If this were an Excel template, I would do this using the following snippet:

```
xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open("book.xltx", Editable: true);
```

However, I don't see anything similar in Visio.

```
vsoApp.Documents.Open("template.vstx");
```

This method Opens the file in Visio as a document, and not a template. So the file is silently saved as a document, unless the SaveAs command used, and template is explicitly selected as the file type.

There is an OpenEx method that offers a number of optional arguments, but none appear to allow the file to be opened as a template:

```
vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx("template.vstx", short Flags);
```

All of the flag values in the VisOpenSaveArgs enum for Visio 2013 and later are documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767185.aspx

Using the shell to load Visio should work, since I can right-click on a Visio template, and select Edit to open as a template that is correctly saved as .vstx  file.

I took a look at the commands issued from the popup menu, but the file name appears to be the only argument supplied, so I am not sure what distinguishes the Edit from the Open option. Here are all the command-line switches I could find for Visio 2010 (I couldn't find a reference for 2013, or 2016).

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Visio-2010-F1DE9AF3-8368-4EF0-9A2F-25D430EC5576

The only thing that appears to work, is opening the file, and immediately saving it back as a template, but I hope someone has a better solution.

Comment: The code `vsoApp.Documents.Open("template.vstx")` **does open the template for editing,** it does not create new document based on template. I think there might be some confusion? Or maybe Visio installation issue (try repair maybe?)